# flutter how to detect bottom navigation index changed

Tags: flutter

I'd like to know how to detect the user tapped different index of bottom navigation. 
For example I have 4 items bottom navigation and playing video on index 2. If the user goes to different index or push to next page (when this video page becomes invisible), I want to stop the video. Is there any way to do this? I tried by using `WidgetBinding` but it wasn't fired. 
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: can u share your code ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is in your scaffold, you have a bottom navigation bar  property which you can put many different bottom navigation bar items and each will have an on pressed property. Have two int variables, one called oldIndex and the other is newIndex. When someone taps an item, the newIndex is now equal to the index of the bottom Navigation item and if the newIndex is different from the oldIndex, you'll know the index changes.